# Populating listbox with only one content from several

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

I want to poplulate `tkinter Listbox` with `tuple` if the content exist more than one only one of the content should be inserted.Have searched on this site didn't get answer to resolve that.

```
from tkinter import *


rows = (('python', 'kivy'), ('python', 'tkinter'),("python","wxpython",32),
('PHP', 'bootstrap'),('html', 'ajax'),('html', 'css'), ('python', 'tkinter'))

root = Tk()

l = Listbox(root)

for row in rows:
    if row[0] not in rows:
        l.insert(END, row[0])
l.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What do you expect `if row[0] not in rows:` to do? You are checking if a string is not in a list of tuples. This will always return `True` because the tuple never equals the string. What exactly do you want the result in your Listbox to look like?

Comment: want it like `python, PHP, html`

Comment: Then the easiest thing would be to get the unique values beforehand using something like `unique = set([row[0] for row in rows])`. You can then loop through `unique` without having to bother with an `if`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the comment from **@ fhdrsdg** this how you will go about if to achieve your result.You will use `set` to get the values after that you `loop` over the variable `unique` to insert in the `Listbox`.

```
from tkinter import *


rows = (('python', 'kivy'), ('python', 'tkinter'),("python","wxpython",32),
('PHP', 'bootstrap'),('html', 'ajax'),('html', 'css') )

root = Tk()

l = Listbox(root)

unique =  set([row[0] for row in rows])
for x in unique:
    l.insert(END, x)

l.pack()

root.mainloop()
```